# `git diff --no-merges work ^master ^notinmaster` still shows changes from notinmaster

Tags: git

I sometimes have a `work` branch that's a merge of master and one or more feature branches that haven't yet been merged to master. I can get a log of changes that are only in my `work` branch and not in master nor the "notinmaster" feature branch, e.g.

```
        -B--               <-- notinmaster
       /    \
      /   w--*--d          <-- work
     /   /  /    ·
...-*---*--C------D-...    <-- master
```

by doing `git log --no-merges work ^master ^notinmaster`, which here would show commits `w` and `d`.

However, `D` is actually `git cherry-pick d`. If I hadn't merged `notinmaster` into `work`, I would be able to see with `git diff master` that only the minor changes from `w` where real changes. However, since `notinmaster` is merged into `work`, `git diff master` is too messy to be useful. And it doesn't seem that I can use the `--not`/`^` syntax to exclude `notinmaster` (e.g. `git diff --stat --no-merges work ^master ^notinmaster` gives the same output as `git diff --stat --no-merges work ^master`, at least on git 2.11.0).

Is there a simple way to get this kind of diff, without first reverting all the `notinmaster` commits?

Comment: In essence you are asking git to try to construct a virtual branch containing only the changes applied on the work branch, disregarding any of the changes that came from the notinmaster branch.

Answer (score 1):

The negative commit syntax doesn't work that way with `diff`.

With `log` you're making rules for how much of the commit graph to traverse, so it's perfectly sensible to say "nothing reachable from this point in the graph"; but with `diff` you're just identifying two `TREE`s (often by identifying two commits) and comparing them.  There is no graph traversal to be limited, no way to say "I want changes if they were introduced by this path only".  A path in the `TREE`s is the same, or it's not the same, and that's all `diff` sees.

So the question is what assumptions you're willing to make.  In this example, `git show W` should give the patch you want.  If `W` might really be *n* commits, but you know there's nothing intervening, then you could do `git diff W1^ Wn`.  You could do an interactive rebase, picking just the `w` commits to a new ref, and generate a patch from that.  (You have shown already that you can use `log` - or `rev-list` if you need a lower-level command for scripting, to find the `w` commit(s).

Of course all of that assumes that `d^` in your diagram is a pure merge, and that there's nowhere else for meaningful changes to hide.  If it were me, I'd want to consider ways to simplify my workflow instead of having to reason that much about how changes might or might not be flowing.